# Why do we need to explicitly call zero_grad()?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent

Why do we need to explicitly zero the gradients in PyTorch? Why can't gradients be zeroed when `loss.backward()` is called? What scenario is served by keeping the gradients on the graph and asking the user to explicitly zero the gradients?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

We explicitly need to call `zero_grad()` because, after `loss.backward()` (when gradients are computed), we need to use `optimizer.step()` to proceed gradient descent. More specifically, the gradients are not automatically zeroed because these two operations, `loss.backward()` and `optimizer.step()`, are separated, and `optimizer.step()` requires the just computed gradients.

In addition, sometimes, we need to accumulate gradient among some batches; to do that, we can simply call `backward` multiple times and optimize once.

Comment: Actually, you mention "minibatch" (or "batch subpartition") vs "batch" - it is a case where the accumulation is useful in feed-forward networks (not just RNN). When we want a bigger batch for optimization, but have physical limits (e.g. GPU memory) for increasing the number of samples.

Comment: Can you give an example where we require accumulated gradient?

Comment: @RedFloyd in case you want to effectively train on a big batch size (imagine 64), but your GPU can only fit 32 examples at the same time. You need to cumulate your gradient through 2 steps, and call `optimizer.step()` only once every 2 steps.

Answer (score 8):

There is a cycle in PyTorch:

- Forward when we get output or `y_hat` from the input,
- Calculating  loss where `loss = loss_fn(y_hat, y)`
- `loss.backward` when we calculate the gradients
- `optimizer.step` when we update parameters

Or in code:

```
for mb in range(10): # 10 mini batches
    y_pred = model(x)
    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

If we would not clear the gradients after the `optimizer.step`, which is the appropriate step or just before the next `backward()` gradients would accumulate.
Here is an example showing accumulation:

```
import torch
w = torch.rand(5)
w.requires_grad_()
print(w) 
s = w.sum() 
s.backward()
print(w.grad) # tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
s.backward()
print(w.grad) # tensor([2., 2., 2., 2., 2.])
s.backward()
print(w.grad) # tensor([3., 3., 3., 3., 3.])
s.backward()
print(w.grad) # tensor([4., 4., 4., 4., 4.])
```

[`loss.backward()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.backward) does not have any way specifying this.

`torch.autograd.backward(tensors, grad_tensors=None, retain_graph=None, create_graph=False, grad_variables=None)`

From all the options you can specify there is no way to zero the gradients manually. Like this in previous mini example:

```
w.grad.zero_()
```

There was some discussion on doing `zero_grad()` every time with `backward()` (obviously previous gradients) and to keep grads with [`preserve_grads=True`](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-do-we-need-to-set-the-gradients-manually-to-zero-in-pytorch/4903/8), but this never came to life.

Answer (score 7):

I have a use case for the current setup in PyTorch.

If one is using a recurrent neural network (RNN) that is making predictions at every step, one might want to have a hyperparameter that allows one to accumulate gradients back in time. Not zeroing the gradients at every time step allows for one to use back-propagating through time (BPTT) in interesting and novel ways.

If you would like more info on BPTT or RNNs see the article [*Recurrent Neural Networks Tutorial, Part 3 – Backpropagation Through Time and Vanishing Gradients*](http://www.wildml.com/2015/10/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-3-backpropagation-through-time-and-vanishing-gradients/) or [*The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Recurrent Neural Networks*](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/).

Comment: This answer needs to be clearer. Maybe an example would help.

Comment: Here is the explanation from the examples   +    # gradients for the variables it will update (which are the learnable
 +    # weights of the model). This is because by default, gradients are
 +    # accumulated in buffers( i.e, not overwritten) whenever .backward()
 +    # is called. Checkout docs of torch.autograd.backward for more details.
      optimizer.zero_grad()

Answer (score 4):

Leaving the gradients in place before calling `.step()` is useful in case you'd like to accumulate the gradient across multiple batches (as others have mentioned).

It's also useful for *after* calling `.step()` in case you'd like to implement momentum for SGD, and various other methods may depend on the values from the previous update's gradient.