# Numerical inprecision in pytorch-lightning's Gradient Accumulation?

Tags: floating-point, precision, pytorch-lightning

In my understanding of Gradient Accumulation (e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067400/understanding-accumulated-gradients-in-pytorch) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001598/why-do-we-need-to-call-zero-grad-in-pytorch/48009142#48009142)) the result of computing with `batch_size = x` vs. `accumulate_gradient = h, batch size = x/h` should be the same.

So those three samples should compute the same thing in pytorch-lightning:

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl

pl.seed_everything(42)

batch_size = 8
trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=1)

batch_size = 8
trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=1, accumulate_grad_batches=1)

batch_size = 4
trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=1, accumulate_grad_batches=2)
```

However, they do not. The weights of the model differ slightly (~ e⁻5) in all three cases after just a few hundred batches.

---

Here is a full reproducible example:

[python 3.11.5, pytorch-lightning 2.0.9]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
import pytorch_lightning as pl
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor

#seed everything
pl.seed_everything(42)

# happens with this dataset and also my original working dataset, MasakhaNER
training_data = datasets.CIFAR10(
    root="data",
    train=True,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor()
)

test_data = datasets.CIFAR10(
    root="data",
    train=False,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor()
)

# happens with this CNN, but also with an AutoEncoder and a huggingface BERT model
class Network(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 3, padding=1)
        self.pool = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(32 * 16 * 16, 128)
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(128, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(torch.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 32 * 16 * 16)
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        inputs, labels = batch
        outputs = self(inputs)
        loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(outputs, labels)

        self.writeWeights(inputs, batch_idx)

        return loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
# also happens with SDG
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.001)

  
    # the weight after the last batch should be the same across all all versions, but is not!
    def writeWeights(self, x, batch_idx):
        if ACC:
            if (accumulate_gradient == 1):
                path = "weight_tracker_a1.csv"
            else:
                path = "weight_tracker_a.csv"
        else:
            path = "weight_tracker.csv"

        np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': '{: e}'.format})
        df = pandas.read_csv(path)
        params = list(self.parameters())[0]
        params = params.detach().cpu().numpy()
        df = df._append({"shape": x.shape, "batch_idx": batch_idx, "weights_1": params}, ignore_index=True)
        df.to_csv(path, float_format='{.e}'.format, index=False)



#Set the 3 different test options here:
ACC = True
#Set accumulate_gradient to 1 or 2 if ACC = True for logging
accumulate_gradient = 2
#set accumulate gradient here manually for training!
#also happens without limit_train_batches
trainer = pl.Trainer(limit_train_batches=limit_train_batches, max_epochs=1, accumulate_grad_batches=2)

if ACC:
    if (accumulate_gradient == 1):
        batch_size = 16
        limit_train_batches = 100
        df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=["shape", "batch_idx", "weights_1"])
        df.to_csv("weight_tracker_a1.csv", float_format='{e}'.format, index=False)
    else:
        batch_size = 8
        limit_train_batches = 200
        df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=["shape", "batch_idx", "weights_1"])
        df.to_csv("weight_tracker_a.csv", float_format='{e}'.format, index=False)

else:
    batch_size = 16
    limit_train_batches = 100
    df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=["shape", "batch_idx", "weights_1"])
    df.to_csv("weight_tracker.csv", float_format='{e}'.format, index=False)


# init stuff
train_dataloader = DataLoader(training_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

model = Network()

#train
trainer.fit(model=model, train_dataloaders=train_dataloader)
```

I tried switching the learning rate, optimizer, dataset and model; the difference in the 3 versions persists. I also tried it on CPU and 2 different GPUs, difference persists.

I'd like to understand where exactly this difference comes from and if it can be eradicated, any ideas?